# Avoid users with invalid format time SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Here is my simple query

```
SELECT
playerId,
max(accountlevel) as level,
max(appActiveTime) as overall_time,
max(matchcount) as matchcount
FROM client
WHERE partition_0 = '2019' 
AND partition_1 = '03'
AND install_date BETWEEN date('2019-03-01')  AND date('2019-03-20')
AND date BETWEEN date('2019-03-01')  AND date('2019-03-31')
AND accountagedays = 0
GROUP BY playerId
```

And Athena returns me

```
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2019-0+-28T23:43:57.4142360Z" is malformed at "+-28T23:43:57.4142360Z"
```

I wonder how to avoid this message?

Comment: Use TRY_CONVERT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Depends what you're using, SQL Server or MySQL (I suspect the latter as `date('2019-03-01')` is not valid T-SQL). But the real problem is you're storing date(time) data in a string datatype. Always use an appropriate datatype for your  data, and a `varchar` is not the correct datatype for a Date.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: can you provide sample data with temp table.

Comment: Regardless of RDBMS, the correct solution is to store dates as date datatype.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . Or at the very minimum, add a `check` constraint.

Comment: Amazon Athena uses the Presto DBMS, if I'm not mistaken. I've updated the tags accordingly. Presto uses standard SQL compliant date literals, e.g. `date '2019-03-01'` (no parentheses). Use these. Then, what data types are your columns `client.install_date` and `client.date`?

Answer (score 0):

It is for SQL Server: I would suggest Use ISDATE function to validate the input then cast it, if it is correct date format then it should cast and check the between the given date. you can use a string to validate date or not. below code is just to give you idea how you can check and cast accordingly. if you provide temp table with data and column type then actual result could be achieved.

```
declare  @install_date datetime= '2019-03-01'
select CAST(IIF(ISDATE(@install_date) = 1,@install_date,'1900-01-01') as Date)
go
declare  @install_date varchar(10)= '2019-23-01'
select CAST(IIF(ISDATE(@install_date) = 1,@install_date,'19000101') as Date)
go
declare  @install_date varchar(100)= 'string not a date'
select CAST(IIF(ISDATE(@install_date) = 1,@install_date,'19000101') as Date)
```

Comment: Careful with `ISDATE`, it brings back false positive/negatives. Example: `SELECT CAST(IIF(ISDATE(2017) = 1, 2017,'19000101') AS date);` Which errors. For SQL Server `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` are far superior functions.

Comment: ISDATE accepts character string or express which converts to character string, your given sample is passing an int which is not correct. [ISDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What do you mean *"is not correct"*? `ISDATE` will accept an `int` as an input value, as the function will implicitly convert it to a `varchar`. That is a major problem because `2017` and `'2017'` are **very** different values. `SELECT CONVERT(date,2017)` will fail, but `SELECT CONVERT(date,'2017')` will not. But for both values `ISDATE` returns 1: `SELECT ISDATE(2017), ISDATE('2017');` this is but one reason why `ISDATE` is a bad function and should be avoided,

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be37a8a7bc7e012f4f8225a928ef161d)